# Why ng-repeat records multiply in combobox in Aspnet Mvc?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs ng-repeat for a combobox but it multiply records that n*n times.(if there is 5 record then it show 5*5=25 records)

I use ng-repeat like this:

```
<div class="profile-info-value userbase">
        <select class="form-control" id="DepositorID" name="DepositorID" ng-model="SearchModel.DepositorID" sc-model="SearchModel.DepositorID" sc-nullable="1">
                <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                <option ng-repeat="item_ in SearchModelDepositorIDs" value="{{item_.DEPO_ID}}">{{item_.DEPO_DESCRIPTION}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

and I fill SearchModelDepositorIDs like below:

```
$.post($scope.addressgetdepolist).done(function (Result) {
        if (Result.Success) {
                $scope['SearchModelDepositorIDs'] = Result.Data;
                $scope.$apply();
                CloseWaiting();
        }
```

I call this method once on formLoad.

As result returned 15 records and showed 225 records:
[image]

When debug I see list has 15 records but anyway ng-repeat multiply records.

Can you help me for this?

**Edit:**
Result.Data:
[image]

Comment: can you include content of Result.Data please

Comment: ok. it is added.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be coming through. Can you check if there was an error when adding it?

Comment: Do you have any `$watch` handlers set on `SearchModelDepositorIDs` that might be pushing new elements onto `$scope.SearchModelDepositorIDs`?

Comment: there is no any error message @hmiedema9.

Comment: No I have don't  I use @SteveDanner. I use SearchModelDepositorIDs on just that two points in all of project.

Comment: I see the image now.

Comment: What happens if you remove `$scope.$apply()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with ng-options using by an advice from my friend on Twitter.

That's it:

```
<div class="profile-info-value userbase">
        <select class="form-control searchablecombobox" ng-model="SearchModel.DepositorID" ng-options="item_.DEPO_ID as item_.DEPO_DESCRIPTION for item_ in SearchModelDepositorIDs">
                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        </select>
</div>
```